# How to update by query with script and nested new fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to update my mapping in elastic
here is example:
current mapping

```
{
filed1: 6,
filed2: "some string"
}
```

I need update it to this

```
{
outer: {
    filed1: 6,
    filed2: "some string"
  }
}
```

I do it with update_by_query api and this request

```
{
"script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.outer.field1 = ctx._source.field1; ctx._source.outer.field2 = ctx._source.field2;",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
}
```

but I got null pointer exception because there is no `outer` in documents yet

```
"type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "compile error",
        "script_stack": [
            "... ctx._source.outer.fiel ...",
            "                     ^---- HERE"
        ],
```

How could I change request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
    "source": "ctx._source.outer = ['field1': ctx._source.remove('field1'), 'field2': ctx._source.remove('field2')];",
```